# how to measure similarity of two datasets (matrices) of different length

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, statistical-significance, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, similarities

There are [related](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194023/how-to-measure-similarity-of-two-lists-of-continuous-data-with-different-length) questions being asked already but my problem is i can't find a good method of measuring similarity between two datasets that are represented by various lengths of matrices. For instance, first dataset is a sensor data with x,y,z,gyro,acc features of 1000 records. The second dataset's features are the same but with 1500 records. So how do I compute the similarity between these two.

I've used [dynamic time warping](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjArbraxILNAhWEVD4KHfzxDSgQFggnMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FDynamic_time_warping&usg=AFQjCNGUHLPy3D5wqDcExk0GfqyaGOJpGg) (DTW) but not sure about it because it is mostly used for time-based operations but my dataset doesn't contain any temporal info. Also, it doesn't output a score between [0-1], so not sure how to scale it.
I checked [Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test), as well, but it can give me the difference between only a particular feature (column) of different size. I thought of measuring the distance for each column separately and summing it up, but haven't tried yet.

Comment: What does "similarity" mean to you in your situation?

Comment: I want to know whether the datasets were generated by the same user or not

Comment: Would it be enough to see if the variables had similar means, etc?

Comment: There are lot of users, and each user has many features. I need a more robust way because I'll run an algorithm on the users whose data change at different sessions.

Comment: If these are time series data, and you believe same user will generate similar time series, you can use [cross-correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) as a measure of similarity

Comment: @A.Ray it measures the similarity between vectors, right? Is there a way to use it for matrices?

Comment: Yes it is generally done for vectors, but it is not difficult to extend it to a matrix. For two time series vectors $x,y$ normally we compute cross correlation something like $\sigma_{x,y}(T)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma_{xx}(0)\sigma_{yy}(0)}}\frac{1}{N-1}\sum (x_{t-T}-\mu_x)(y_t-\mu_y)$. For the matrix case since $x_t,y_t$ are vectors themselves, simply take their inner product. $\sigma_{x,y}(T)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma_{xx}(0)\sigma_{yy}(0)}}\frac{1}{N-1}\sum (x_{t-T}-\mu_x)^T(y_t-\mu_y)$.

Comment: Another approach maybe compute cross correlation for each row separately. In your case compute 5 cross-correlations for x,y,z,gyro,acc. Then you can compute a weighted sum to find a single cross-correlation. Optimize the weight from a training set.

Comment: Have you looked at mutual information, which is really good for nonlinear comparisons: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information

Comment: @theideasmith but mutual information is applicable only if joint PDF is given, so a problem of estimation of PDF arises.

Comment: Ok – so you estimate PDF, big deal. It gives a nice nonlinear correlation metric and is perfect for this kind of data (could also do Kullback Leibler divergence). Alternatively the OP can just throw away 500 datapoints and do a standard cross correlation, or maybe do a sliding window cross correlation. Cross correlation wouldn't account for translation invariance across datasets.

Comment: Would anyone suggest using PCA for this purpose? Is there anything wrong with making PCA and use one of the methods mentioned above? @A.Ray

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is related to domain adaptation and the term "discrepancy" they use in the literature between two domains.
Check Ben David papers on discrepancy. There is a simplified measure defined as the classification error (or accuracy) of a classifier that discriminates samples of one dataset from the other.

Comment: Can you expand a bit your answer?

Comment: Lets say you have datasets A and B. You build the new dataset X composed of both A and B with labels a if the data belongs to A and b if data belongs to B. Then you train a classifier on the new dataset that discriminates a from b. you measure abs(2*acc-1) where acc is the accuracy between 0 and 1. If the datasets are similar, you will get 0.5 accuracy for two class classification which is the minimum of the discrepancy defined above. otherwise it will return positive nonzero discrepancy.